# Finding the summation of the floor of the series.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Can someone help me the summation of the given series.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor$$

Negative of the above summation looks similar to the expansion of the $\log(1-x)$ without the floor.

Comment: According to a [recent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/485879/7933), it is $n\log n + (2\gamma-1)n + O(n^{1/2})$.

Comment: As the floor is being used can't we get the numerical value..

Comment: [OEIS A006218](http://oeis.org/A006218) gives various formulae and references

Comment: Yes, but we can give an approximation, which is what I gave. @user1580096

Comment: @user1580096 and so? for example you can easily prove that $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\bigl\lfloor\frac{a+r}n\bigr\rfloor=a$ for any $a,n\in\mathbb Z$ with $n\ne0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are right when you call your sum a "series", because you can change the upper limit of summation $n$ by $\infty$ (because $\lfloor n/i\rfloor=0$ for $i>n$)...but I think that it is better you call it simply "a sum".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [OEIS A$006218$](http://oeis.org/A006218). No closed form is known; the problem of finding a precise asymptotic estimate is the [Dirichlet divisor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem). You’ll find references, asymptotic estimates, and other information at the two links and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletDivisorProblem.html).

A useful tip: I simply calculated the first half-dozen terms and ran them through [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](http://oeis.org/); that’s worth a try any time you want information about an integer sequence.