# Formula for summation of integer division series

Tags: summation

Consider '\' to be the integer division operator, i.e.,

$a$ \ $b = \lfloor a / b\rfloor$

Is there a formula to compute  the following summation:

N\1 + N\2 + N\3 + ... + N\N

Comment: Are you solving the Cool Guys problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a closed form, but an alternate characterization of this sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor n/k\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^nd(k)\tag{1}
$$
where $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$. This can be seen by noticing that $\lfloor n/k\rfloor$ increases by $1$ when $k\mid n$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\lfloor n/k\rfloor&1&2&3&4&5&6&k\\
\hline\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&\color{#C00000}{1}&0&0&0&0&0\\
2&\color{#C00000}{2}&\color{#C00000}{1}&0&0&0&0\\
3&\color{#C00000}{3}&1&\color{#C00000}{1}&0&0&0\\
4&\color{#C00000}{4}&\color{#C00000}{2}&1&\color{#C00000}{1}&0&0\\
5&\color{#C00000}{5}&2&1&1&\color{#C00000}{1}&0\\
6&\color{#C00000}{6}&\color{#C00000}{3}&\color{#C00000}{2}&1&1&\color{#C00000}{1}\\
n
\end{array}
$$
In the table above, each red entry indicates that $k\mid n$, and each red entry is $1$ greater than the entry above it. Thus, the sum of each row increases by $1$ for each divisor of $n$.

A simple upper bound is given by
$$
n(\log(n)+\gamma)+\frac12\tag{2}
$$
This is because we have the following bound for the $n^\text{th}$ [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number):
$$
H_n\le\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}\tag{3}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

**Research Results**

After looking into this a bit, I found that the [Dirichlet Divisor Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem) involves estimating the exponent $\theta$ in the approximation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nd(k)=n\log(n)+(2\gamma-1)n+O\left(n^\theta\right)
$$
Dirichlet showed that $\theta\le\frac12$ and Hardy showed that $\theta\ge\frac14$.

There is no closed form known for $(1)$.